# Generating all real numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can somebody explain to me why you can write any real number $\alpha \neq 0$ in the form form $α = ±2^{3n}r$,
where 1 ≤ r < 8 and n ∈ $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Does it help to notice that $2^{3n}=8^n$?

Comment: Also, do you know about logarithms? Specifically, can you use $\log_8 \alpha$ somehow?

Comment: Yes, however that is as far as I have gotten with it. Is is because r is a real number between 1 and 8, so you multiply your power by that to get every number in between?

Comment: I think you have a good intuition, you “just” need to formalise it. (I appreciate it is easier said than done.) More precisely, you are starting from $\alpha$, you need to *find* $n$ and $r$ and the sign (whether it will be “plus” or “minus”) that will produce precisely the given $\alpha$. Logarithm helps to find $n$, for example.

Comment: So, $\forall  \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$,with $1 \leq r < 8, \exists n \in \mathbb{r}$ such that $\alpha = 8^{n}r = 2^{3n}r$ where n = $log_{8}\frac{\alpha}{r}$

Comment: that should say $\exists$ n $\in \mathbb{R}$  and not  $\exists$ n $\in r$

Answer (score 0):

Which numbers can you form with n = 0? Which numbers can you form with n = 1 or n = -1? If you calculate the union of these thee sets, what is it? The same with n = +/- 2 or +/- 3? All seven cases combined, what happens?

Can you figure it out now?

Comment: There aren’t seven, but infinitely many cases of this sort. But yes, the OP may find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\alpha>0$. Let $n=\lfloor\log_8\alpha\rfloor\in\mathbb Z$, where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ means “$x$ rounded down to the nearest integer”. Now, take $r=\frac{\alpha}{2^{3n}}=\frac{\alpha}{8^n}$. By construction, we already have that  $2^{3n}r=\alpha$. What remains is to prove that $1\le r\lt 8$.

As it is well known, $\lfloor x\rfloor\le x<\lfloor x\rfloor+1$ for any real $x$, and so (by setting $x=\log_8\alpha$) you get $n\le\log_8\alpha<n+1$, i.e. $2^{3n}\le\alpha<8\cdot 2^{3n}$ (power $8$ to all the sides in the inequalities), i.e. $1\le r<8$ (divide everything by $2^{3n}$).

That solves the problem for positive $\alpha$. If $\alpha<0$ then $-\alpha>0$, so (per previous proof) $-\alpha=2^{3n}r$ for a suitable $n\in\mathbb Z$ and $1\le r<8$, but then $\alpha=-2^{3n}r$.